# Matlab: Labelling the y axis

Tags: matlab

I have plotted a dot raster plot divided into various segments, which I would like to label. In my case, I have different attenuation values for the same frequency value and want to label the attenuation values in the y-axis.

Comment: You might have it easiest if you use the plot edit tools (in the figure window). If they don't help please post a picture where you specifically point out the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little unclear exactly what your trying to do but if you mean to label the entire axis using:

`ylabel('sometext','fontsize',12);`

If you mean to label specific ticks on the axis try using something like :

```
set(gca,'Ytick',[0:3],'YtickLabel',{'hello','world','foo','bar'});
```

**Edit:**
You would want to do something like this.

```
set(gca,'Ytick',[1:20:120],'YtickLabel',{'label1','label2','label3',etc...});
```

Comment: @user3364070 You have deleted your comment that explained your issue in more detail, why? Does this answer your question?